# Add a label next to my form inputs that has a dynamic size

Tags: javascript, html, css

After a few trials I managed to create [these](http://codepen.io/greenleafone7/pen/BNEZRB) form textareas that look pretty nice (or so I think).

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <form class="cf">
    <div class="">
      <header class="">Name</header>
      <input class="shadowDepth1" type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
      <header>Email</header>
      <input class="shadowDepth1" type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
      <header>Subject</header>
      <input class="shadowDepth1" type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

The next step I believe would be to add a label next to each one that describes the input.

What I want though is for the label to look just like the inputs (maybe with bold or a different color) but occupy space dynamically.

So if the label's contents are big then it will push the input that is next to it, in order to accommodate itself.

A somewhat close example would be [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CufonizedFlyOutMenu/) effect.

How can I make this sort of dynamic relation between label and input?

**EDIT:**

[This](http://codepen.io/greenleafone7/pen/yNroBP) is basically the idea for the input. I think that because the `input` width is to 100% it will not go next to my label even with `float: left`. Making it with a width of eg. 70% will fix the issue but it will remove the dynamic part. Because in the end I want all my text inputs to end at the same area.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to float your elements to the right. First switch order of input and header (so input comes first), because after floating to the right the first element will be on right side. Then add class to inputs and headers and set attribute "float: right" to this class. And last put empty "<div></div>" after each header, so it will break to new line. Last you can float entire form to the left, if you dont want to have it on right side.

```html
<style>
.di-wrapper{
  float: right;
}


.di{
float: left;
}

</style>


<div class="col-lg-6">
    <form class="cf">
    <div class="di">
      <input class="di-wrapper shadowDepth1" type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
   <header class="di-wrapper">Name</header>
      <div></div>
      <input class="di-wrapper shadowDepth1" type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
   <header class="di-wrapper">Email</header>
      <div></div>
      <input class="di-wrapper shadowDepth1" type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
   <header class="di-wrapper">Subject</header>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried using float but there was no effect. Maybe because some other command is interfering with it. You may want to look at my edit above.